# Two tests passed but Elasticsearch shows the results of only first one

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I got the following two tests:

```
@Test
    public void shouldCreateSingleBookEntityWithRepository(){

        //given
        Book book = Book.builder().id("1").title("Clean Code").build();
        IndexQuery indexQuery = getIndexQuery(book);

        //when
        String documentId = bookService.saveBook(indexQuery);

        //then
        assertThat(bookService.findOne(book.getId()), is(notNullValue()));
        assertThat(bookService.findOne(book.getId()).getId(), is(documentId));
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldCheckAllDocumentsPresenceAfterInsertSingleThreaded(){

        //given
        List<IndexQuery> indexQueries = new ArrayList<>();

        indexQueries.add(Book.builder().id("1").title("Learn Scala").build().getIndexQuery());
        indexQueries.add(Book.builder().id("2").title("Clean Code").build().getIndexQuery());
        indexQueries.add(Book.builder().id("3").title("Head First: JPA").build().getIndexQuery());
        indexQueries.add(Book.builder().id("4").title("Effective Java").build().getIndexQuery());

        bookService.saveBulkOfBooks(indexQueries);

        SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                .withIndices(INDEX_NAME)
                .withTypes(BOOK_TYPE_NAME)
                .withQuery(matchAllQuery())
                .build();

        //when
        Long bookCount = elasticsearchTemplate.count(searchQuery);
        System.out.print("\n\n##########################################\n"
                +indexQueries.size()+bookCount+ bookService.findOne("2").getTitle()+
                "\n####################################################\n\n");
        //then
        assertThat(bookCount, is(Long.valueOf(indexQueries.size())));
        assertThat(bookService.findOne("1").getTitle(), is("Learn Scala"));
        assertThat(bookService.findOne("2").getTitle(), is("Clean Code"));
        assertThat(bookService.findOne("3").getTitle(), is("Head First: JPA"));
        assertThat(bookService.findOne("4").getTitle(), is("Effective Java"));
    }
```

Each time I run both tests they **pass**. However, the results stored in ES are representing only one `book` form first test.

```
GET /bookshop/book/_search
{
   "took": 34,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 2,
      "successful": 2,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "bookshop",
            "_type": "book",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "title": "Clean Code",
               "id": "1"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

When I ignore the first test I got the result of 4 books from the second test in ES.

I got only `@Before` method in my test case

```
@Before
    public void before() {
         elasticsearchTemplate.deleteIndex(Book.class);
         elasticsearchTemplate.createIndex(Book.class);
         elasticsearchTemplate.putMapping(Book.class);
         elasticsearchTemplate.refresh(Book.class);
    }
```

**Why the tests pass but the ES shows only one document book from the first test?**

Answer (score 1):

It's because the method with `@Before` annotation will execute before any method marked with @Test. You can try to use [`@BeforeClass`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html). However, the issue that I can see in using `@BeforeClass` is you can't access your `elasticsearchTemplate` there, the method must be `static`.

You can use `@PostConstruct` instead. e.g.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {

    elasticsearchTemplate.deleteIndex(Book.class);
    elasticsearchTemplate.createIndex(Book.class);
    elasticsearchTemplate.putMapping(Book.class);
    elasticsearchTemplate.refresh(Book.class);
}
```

Comment: Well the @Before method is ok, because it is executed before each test. Also before second test the index should be removed and new index should be created. The issue was that the `bookService` was probably wrongly autowired. Now I have returned to previous git version where it was ok :) I have upvoted though.